# Remove active state on clicked item when scrolling up or down

Tags: html, jquery, css

After searching for several days for a solution to my problem without any luck I
decided to write a post here. I am currently building an one page website with html&css&jquery.
My menu works great when I scroll up or down. It also works when I click on a menu link as it goes to the wanted section. The problem occurs when I scroll down or up a section and the active class stays on the clicked menu link.

Here is an example of my page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

  $(window).on("resize scroll", function() {
    $("section.subpage").each(function() {
      var activeSections = $(this).attr("id");

      if ($("section[id=" + activeSections + "]").isInViewport()) {
        $("#menu-" + activeSections).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active").removeAttr("class");

      } else {
        $("#menu-" + activeSections).removeAttr("class");
      }
    });

  });


  function scrollThere(targetElement, speed) {
    $("html, body")
      .stop()
      .animate({
        scrollTop: targetElement.offset().top
      }, 900, "swing");
  }

  $("#main-menu li a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var startOfName = $(this).attr("href").indexOf("#"),
      clickRef = $(this)
      .attr("href")
      .slice(startOfName + 1),
      targetEl = $("section[id=" + clickRef + "]");
    scrollThere(targetEl, 900);
  });
  $(window).on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    var div1y = $("#superLeague").offset().top,
      div2y = $("#premierLeague").offset().top,
      div3y = $("#leagueOne").offset().top,
      div4y = $("#leagueTwo").offset().top,
      lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
      scrollDirection,
      targetUp,
      targetDown,
      targetElement;

    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      scrollDirection = "up";
    } else if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
      scrollDirection = "down";
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    if (lastScrollTop === div1y) {
      targetUp = $("#superLeague");
      targetDown = $("#premierLeague");
    } else if (lastScrollTop === div2y) {
      targetUp = $("#superLeague");
      targetDown = $("#leagueOne");
    } else if (lastScrollTop === div3y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueOne");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    } else if (lastScrollTop === div4y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueOne");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    } else if (lastScrollTop < div2y) {
      targetUp = $("#superLeague");
      targetDown = $("#premierLeague");
    } else if (lastScrollTop < div3y) {
      targetUp = $("#premierLeague");
      targetDown = $("#leagueOne");

    } else if (lastScrollTop < div4y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueOne");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    } else if (lastScrollTop > div4y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueTwo");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    }

    if (scrollDirection === "down") {
      targetElement = targetDown;
    } else if (scrollDirection === "up") {
      targetElement = targetUp;
    }
    scrollThere(targetElement, 900);
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#main-menu {
  margin: 0;
}

#main-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu.active {
  background: #ba0032;
}

#main-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}

#main-menu li a:hover,
#main-menu li a:focus,
#main-menu li.active {
  background: #ba0032;
}

.subpage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.subpage h2 {
  color: #ba0032;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.subpage p {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.subpage:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul id="main-menu">
      <li id="menu-superLeague"><a href="#superLeague">Super League</a>

      </li>
      <li id="menu-premierLeague"><a href="#premierLeague">Premier League</a>

      </li>
      <li id="menu-leagueOne"><a href="#leagueOne">League One</a>

      </li>
      <li id="menu-leagueTwo"><a href="#leagueTwo">League Two</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


  <section id="superLeague" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      Super League
    </h2>
    <p>
      Authoritatively network high-quality initiatives for functional opportunities. Globally envisioneer pandemic metrics vis-a-vis flexible e-markets. Rapidiously integrate cooperative systems whereas flexible communities. Assertively formulate high-payoff
      "outside the box" thinking whereas cross functional methodologies. Enthusiastically redefine multifunctional convergence rather than interdependent mindshare.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="premierLeague" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      Premier League
    </h2>
    <p>Seamlessly impact multidisciplinary sources for covalent bandwidth. Globally maintain premier action items rather than team building expertise. Conveniently underwhelm resource-leveling value before customer directed results. Seamlessly integrate
      superior functionalities rather than market-driven materials. Energistically evolve ethical web services and 24/7 partnerships. </p>
  </section>

  <section id="leagueOne" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      League One
    </h2>
    <p>
      Distinctively visualize optimal benefits for fully researched e-markets. Assertively integrate B2B expertise whereas flexible action items. Enthusiastically orchestrate virtual convergence without bricks-and-clicks content. Rapidiously streamline goal-oriented
      benefits and web-enabled leadership skills. Completely architect an expanded array of intellectual capital before real-time portals.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="leagueTwo" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      League 2
    </h2>
    <p>
      Quickly coordinate user-centric platforms via seamless e-services. Dynamically redefine value-added infomediaries with standards compliant convergence. Competently productivate functionalized e-services without standardized core competencies. Credibly
      leverage other's orthogonal e-markets via diverse content. Dramatically synergize robust supply chains and future-proof internal or "organic" sources.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Hopefully someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that the `<a>` inside each li could be focused after you clicked on it, so I've added `$("#menu-" + activeSections +" a").blur();` to your code.

```
$("section.subpage").each(function() {
  var activeSections = $(this).attr("id");

  if ($("section[id=" + activeSections + "]").isInViewport()) {
    $("#menu-" + activeSections).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active").removeAttr("class");

  } else {
    $("#menu-" + activeSections).removeAttr("class");
    $("#menu-" + activeSections +" a").blur();
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

  $(window).on("resize scroll", function() {
    $("section.subpage").each(function() {
      var activeSections = $(this).attr("id");

      if ($("section[id=" + activeSections + "]").isInViewport()) {
        $("#menu-" + activeSections).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active").removeAttr("class");

      } else {
        $("#menu-" + activeSections).removeAttr("class");
        $("#menu-" + activeSections +" a").blur();
      }
    });

  });


  function scrollThere(targetElement, speed) {
    $("html, body")
      .stop()
      .animate({
        scrollTop: targetElement.offset().top
      }, 900, "swing");
  }

  $("#main-menu li a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var startOfName = $(this).attr("href").indexOf("#"),
      clickRef = $(this)
      .attr("href")
      .slice(startOfName + 1),
      targetEl = $("section[id=" + clickRef + "]");
    scrollThere(targetEl, 900);
  });
  $(window).on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    var div1y = $("#superLeague").offset().top,
      div2y = $("#premierLeague").offset().top,
      div3y = $("#leagueOne").offset().top,
      div4y = $("#leagueTwo").offset().top,
      lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
      scrollDirection,
      targetUp,
      targetDown,
      targetElement;

    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      scrollDirection = "up";
    } else if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
      scrollDirection = "down";
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    if (lastScrollTop === div1y) {
      targetUp = $("#superLeague");
      targetDown = $("#premierLeague");
    } else if (lastScrollTop === div2y) {
      targetUp = $("#superLeague");
      targetDown = $("#leagueOne");
    } else if (lastScrollTop === div3y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueOne");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    } else if (lastScrollTop === div4y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueOne");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    } else if (lastScrollTop < div2y) {
      targetUp = $("#superLeague");
      targetDown = $("#premierLeague");
    } else if (lastScrollTop < div3y) {
      targetUp = $("#premierLeague");
      targetDown = $("#leagueOne");

    } else if (lastScrollTop < div4y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueOne");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    } else if (lastScrollTop > div4y) {
      targetUp = $("#leagueTwo");
      targetDown = $("#leagueTwo");
    }

    if (scrollDirection === "down") {
      targetElement = targetDown;
    } else if (scrollDirection === "up") {
      targetElement = targetUp;
    }
    scrollThere(targetElement, 900);
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#main-menu {
  margin: 0;
}

#main-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu.active {
  background: #ba0032;
}

#main-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}

#main-menu li a:hover,
#main-menu li a:focus,
#main-menu li.active {
  background: #ba0032;
}

.subpage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.subpage h2 {
  color: #ba0032;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.subpage p {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.subpage:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <ul id="main-menu">
      <li id="menu-superLeague"><a href="#superLeague">Super League</a>

      </li>
      <li id="menu-premierLeague"><a href="#premierLeague">Premier League</a>

      </li>
      <li id="menu-leagueOne"><a href="#leagueOne">League One</a>

      </li>
      <li id="menu-leagueTwo"><a href="#leagueTwo">League Two</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


  <section id="superLeague" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      Super League
    </h2>
    <p>
      Authoritatively network high-quality initiatives for functional opportunities. Globally envisioneer pandemic metrics vis-a-vis flexible e-markets. Rapidiously integrate cooperative systems whereas flexible communities. Assertively formulate high-payoff
      "outside the box" thinking whereas cross functional methodologies. Enthusiastically redefine multifunctional convergence rather than interdependent mindshare.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="premierLeague" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      Premier League
    </h2>
    <p>Seamlessly impact multidisciplinary sources for covalent bandwidth. Globally maintain premier action items rather than team building expertise. Conveniently underwhelm resource-leveling value before customer directed results. Seamlessly integrate
      superior functionalities rather than market-driven materials. Energistically evolve ethical web services and 24/7 partnerships. </p>
  </section>

  <section id="leagueOne" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      League One
    </h2>
    <p>
      Distinctively visualize optimal benefits for fully researched e-markets. Assertively integrate B2B expertise whereas flexible action items. Enthusiastically orchestrate virtual convergence without bricks-and-clicks content. Rapidiously streamline goal-oriented
      benefits and web-enabled leadership skills. Completely architect an expanded array of intellectual capital before real-time portals.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="leagueTwo" class="subpage">
    <h2>
      League 2
    </h2>
    <p>
      Quickly coordinate user-centric platforms via seamless e-services. Dynamically redefine value-added infomediaries with standards compliant convergence. Competently productivate functionalized e-services without standardized core competencies. Credibly
      leverage other's orthogonal e-markets via diverse content. Dramatically synergize robust supply chains and future-proof internal or "organic" sources.
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Mange tak. Det fungerer perfekt :D